# Python Request Headers Cookies Issue

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to scrape [this](http://www.sky.com/tv/movie/ali-and-nino-2016) page, but am having problems with the cookies using the below code:

```
            SelectProxy.select_proxy()
            local_proxy = SelectProxy.global_proxy

            session = requests.Session()
            session.proxies = {local_proxy}
            cookies = session.cookies

            url = movie_url

            headers ={
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Cookie': cookies,
            'Host': 'www.sky.com',
            'If-Modified-Since': 'Sat, 18 Aug 2018 14:45:31 GMT',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
            }

            r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The error I am getting is as so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python27\Kodi\Sky Q Movies Scraper.py", line 33, in <module>
    class sky_movies:
  File "G:\Python27\Kodi\Sky Q Movies Scraper.py", line 90, in sky_movies
    r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "G:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 461, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "G:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 394, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "G:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 295, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "G:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 409, in prepare_headers
    check_header_validity(header)
  File "G:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 800, in check_header_validity
    "not %s" % (value, type(value)))
InvalidHeader: Header value <RequestsCookieJar[]> must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>
```

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you `print(type(cookies))` ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the cookies out of your browser, so your script can continue the same session on the server that you started in the browser?

Comment: PS, before posting a long cookie string on a public site like this, you should check it over to make sure it doesn't contain any personal info. I haven't read through that huge string, but I know that AT&T tech support page used to throw your phone number and address, in plain text, into cookies, along with stuff that could be easily decoded to figure out what AT&T plans you own, etc., which would all be a pretty bad thing to post online, and I could easily imagine Sky being just as stupid.

Comment: i have removed now. thanks.

Comment: @gdogg371 It may still be visible in your question's edit history. I don't know exactly how to get that fixed, but I flagged it for a mod to take a look. (In the future, you can do the same thing by clicking the `flag` link under the question. Although if you're less lazy than me, you probably want to look around on [meta] to see the right procedure…)

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to pass the cookies object via the `cookies` parameter of `requests.METHOD` call (e.g. `get()`, `post()`, `head()` etc), not via header directly:

```
session.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

and drop the `Cookie` header altogether.

---

The `cookies` object you have is an instance of the class `requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar`, you can check the attributes on the object via usual manners:

```
vars(cookies)  # preferable
cookies.__dict__
```

and obviously can refer to attributes via the usual dotted lookup.

Comment: Hi. I have amended my question to show the cookies as they appear in chrome tools. i admit cookies are not a strong subject for me and i am getting a little lost...when I had cookies=cookies to session.get and remove Cookies from the header directly, the page is scraped, but the returned result appears to be different from the source code for the page as seen when viewing it directly in chrome...

Comment: ...I am after the synposis, cast and director data...my current request does not seem to be returning the page correctly...

Comment: @gdogg371 You need to look at the cookies your browser passing and match those against `requests`. Also, check out for other headers. As far as passing cookies in `requests`, this is the way to go.

Comment: @gdogg371 This code will correctly handle any cookies the servers sets on the session based on requests you make in that session. But in the browser, you probably made other requests—and ran some JavaScript code—that caused more cookies to be set there than here.

Comment: grrrrr.....issue in the end was the beautifulsoup option i was using...switched from html.parser to lxml and got the desired result. cookies problem did still need sorting beforehand though, so thanks for the input all...

Answer (score 2):

Basically if requests receives any cookies from a server they are wrapped in a CookieJar object. Now you're trying that object in the header, which only accepts strings or bytes.

As heemayl rightfully remarks, usually the best way to work with cookies in requests is by passing them through the cookies parameter in any request function (e.g. get, post, head etc.).

If you want to pass your own cookies, you need to create a CookieJar object yourself, set the cookies on the jar, and pass that through the cookies parameter, as described [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies).

Comment: hi. please see my comments on his answer for the issues i am still having. thanks.